# Cómo llamar a una segunda llave en un diccionario usando HDF5Matrix?

Tags: python, keras

Estoy tratando de cargar un archivo `.h5` usando esta documentación [`HDF5Matrix`](https://keras.io/utils/#HDF5Matrix):

```
test_images = HDF5Matrix(train_path+train_file,'images')
```

pero estoy obteniendo este error:

> KeyError: "Unable to open object (object 'images' doesn't exist)"

Se que es necesario usar esta sintaxis para llamar una segunda llave en un diccionario `['train']['images']`.

Normalmente uso esta instrucción para abrir archivos `.h5`:

```
with h5py.File(train_path+train_file, 'r') as hf:
      train_images = hf['train']['images'][:]
```

Mi pregunta es: Es posible tener acceso a la segunda llave para usar la sintaxis `HDF5Matrix`?

Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente lo logré!

Es muy fácil, archivos tipo `h5` tienen esta estructura:

```
file
  Group
    Dataset
```

Asi que si queremos tener acceso al `Dataset` usando `HDF5Matrix('path/file','dataset')`. Solo tenemos que llamar al `Group` primero. Esto será así:

```
from keras.utils import HDF5Matrix

x_data = HDF5Matrix('path/file', 'group/dataset')
```